# Incorrect TEMPLATE_DIRS location

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy my Django application at webfaction but the path to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings seems to be incorrect.

My project is located under `webapps/django/edmhunters`

My settings.py file is under `webapps/django/edmhunters/edmhunters`

My template folder is at `webapps/django/edmhunters/templates`

In my settings.py file this is what i'm doing

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

But I still get TemplateDoesNotExist error. What would be the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `templates` directory is one more level up, you can do as below to get parent directory and use it to get templates directory.

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(SETTINGS_PATH))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
>       os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, '../templates'), )

use this instead of

> TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
>       os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'), )